# Reactive Code without mongodb in Meteor and using NPM packages with Meteor

Tags: meteor, npm

I am playing around with Meteor and I am trying, to connect the serverside of the application to another server S.
Therefore I want to open an TLS client socket and push the received data to the client, every time the server S transmits data.

Now I have two questions:
Can I require node packages in the usual way (e.g. `var Candle = require('candle');`)?

Is it possible, to create reactive code without writing the received data to a collection, which is stored in the mongodb database?
In other words, I just want to push the data to all clients, without saving it on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1

To require a npm package, you need to install `npm` package via `mrt add npm`.
Then you add `packages.json` file with the list of necessary packages, for example:

```
{
  "candle": "0.4.0",
  "oauth":  "0.9.11"
}
```

Afterwards, you can require the package with `Meteor.require('candle');`.

#### 2

To create a reactive code you use Dependencies – see [the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps). Basically, you create a dep:

```
var dep = new Deps.Dependency();
```

mark the functions that should be recalculated when the dep is changed:

```
Templates.example.something = function() {
    dep.depend();
    ...
}
```

And then change it when necessary:

```
dep.changed();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer your first question.

In order to integrate npm packages, you should add npm package via meteorite and create a  packages.json file as documented here: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-npm

Then you can load npm modules as follows:

```
 var Candle = Meteor.require('candle');
```